# Using LdapConnection to enumerate AD

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices

Is it possible to use an LdapConnection from System.DirectoryServices.Protocols to query Active Directory?

I'm having issues instantiating a PrincipalContext. Here's my code, in case anyone can spot the issue:

```
    private LdapConnection getLdapConnection(string username, string password, string ldapServer, bool secured)
    {
        int port = secured ? 636 : 389;

        LdapConnection connection = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(ldapServer, port, false, false));

        if (secured)
        {
            connection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;
            connection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;
        }


        connection.Credential = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        connection.AuthType = AuthType.Basic;
        connection.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate += (conn, cert) => { return true; };
        connection.Bind();

        return connection;
    }
```

When trying to instantiate the Principal Context I am using

```
        PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(
            ContextType.Domain,
            ldapServer,
            null,
            useSsl ? ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer | ContextOptions.SimpleBind : ContextOptions.SimpleBind,
            username,
            password);
```

I am passing the same values in, for the sake of completeness username is in the format of `domain\user` and the ldapServer is in the format of `server.domain.com` with ldapServer having :636 appended when creating the Principal Context.

The server I am connecting to has certificate issues which I guess could be preventing this as the LdapConnection is set to return true for verification. This isn't an issue as it's trusted. I don't have access to the server and as such cannot change this.

Comment: What is the error you are getting.

Comment: The server could not be contacted.

Comment: try your ldap server as `dc=MyDomain,dc=com`

Comment: You can always check if a tcp port is responding by using telnet to connect to it. You'll either get connected or get an error. Once connected you quit telnet by hitting the ctrl-] key then typing quit and enter. If server cannot be contacted is the error, your AD admin may not have set up secure ldap.

Comment: @James the server definitely has LDAPS enabled - the first example on port 636 with SSL works.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understant the container parameter can't be `null` when you target a domain. Can you just try this constructor :

```
PrincipalContext domainContextMonou = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,
                                                           "server.domain.com :389",
                                                           "dc=domain,dc=com",
                                                           username,
                                                           password);
```

And then this one :

```
PrincipalContext domainContextMonou = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,
                                                           "server.domain.com :636",
                                                           "dc=domain,dc=com",
                                                           useSsl ? ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer | ContextOptions.SimpleBind : ContextOptions.SimpleBind,
                                                           username,
                                                           password);
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. The top one won't work as 389 (unsecured LDAP) is not enabled on the server. It requires LDAPS.

The second one I tried, both with server.domain.com and ldaps://server.domain.com. The URI of the remote LDAPS server is in the form of remote.{domain}.net.au. I tried dc={domain},dc=net,dc=au. Can you confirm what the correct DC should be? Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: The third parameter is the Distinguiched Name of the object where you begin your search. I you have no iea of the DN just try to launche LDP.EXE (connect, bind, and view tree). for me for a DNS name domain.net.au the DN should be "dc=domain,dc=net,dc=au"

Answer (score 0):

I suspect part of your problem with the LDAP code is that you're using `AuthType.Basic`. Try `Negotiate` instead.